# Not able to display string using a user define String class

Tags: c++, constructor

I made the following program which has a class String, that would work as user defined string type.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class String{
    char *s;

    public:
        int length;
        String()
        {
            s=NULL;
            length=0;

        }
        String(char *ss)
        {
            int count=0;
            while(*ss!='\0')
            {
                count ++;
                ss++;

            }
            ss=ss-count;
            s=new char[count];
            length = count;
            s=ss;
        }
        void display()
        {
            int i;
            while (*(s+i)!='\0')
            {
                cout<<*(s+i);
                i++;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    String s1("Hello World");
    //cout<<s1.length;                 //<------remove the // before cout and voila!
    s1.display();

}
```

So, when i run it. I get nothing displayed on the screen but when i run the program after removing the "//" before cout the program displays correctly with correct value of length. Can anyone provide me a good explanation for this behavior ?

Comment: [Can't reproduce the problem](http://ideone.com/5XeLGY)

Comment: This works fine for me.  http://ideone.com/HM3clk

Comment: That while loop would be better expressed as a for loop, but regardless of that, have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? The loop condition might never be met. Also, try adding `std::cout << std::flush` just after the display call.

Comment: Does compiler has to do something with it?I'm using DEV c++. I'll paste the screenshot

Comment: `i` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Smatik _"I'll paste the screenshot "_ No, don't do that, post the exact text.

Comment: Once you fix the issue with `i` being uninitialized then I think this code would make for a good review question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because while the code works there's a number of areas that could be improved on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `display` you do not initialize `i` so you print random garbage, which happens to be a `0` in your test. Printing out `length`happens to put a 0 on the stack which then happens to initialize `i`. Your compiler should warn you about reading an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Nice find!  The big mistake here was disabling or ignoring the compiler warnings that would have answered this question.

Comment: I only got this warning:43 25 C:\Users\dell\Documents\Untitled2.cpp [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]  But yes initialising i=0 works..thanks!

Comment: @Smatik that would mean that you have vital warnings disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is much more complicated.

```
    String(char *ss)          <<< This is source string.
    {
        int count=0;
        while(*ss!='\0')
        {
            count ++;         <<< count will not account for '\0'.
            ss++;

        }
        ss=ss-count;
        s=new char[count];    <<< You are allocating space for 's'
        length = count;
        s=ss;                 <<< And then you are making 's' point to 'ss'
    }
```